# Qt mac switch between panels without changing window

Tags: c++, macos, qt

I extensively researched this topic, mainly hindered by that I'm not sure I'm using the right words to describe my issue.

So the point is I'm developing a GUI application in C++ with Qt. The app is being developped on Mac and ftm it's intended only for mac deployment. 
I want my app to behave much like System Preferences on Mac, thus accessing different views/panes by clicking buttons on the toolbar. 
What I want to avoid is to have one separate window for each pane.

The closest thing I found seems to be `QStackedWidget` however I'm not sure what's the best way for implementing it.

Should I use it as the main class of my application? Or can I treat it as an object of MainWindow? I'm not a `Qt Expert` so any further insight or suggestion will be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You've identified that QStackedWidget allows you to have a stack of QWidgets that can only display one at a time. Are you just looking for confirmation that this is the right way to go, or is there something else you want to know about it? There are plenty of examples on how to use QStackedWidget if you search the web.

Comment: Try defining your 'centralWidget' as QStackedWidget(). As @Merlin069 said, there are a lot of examples out there.

Answer (score 0):

`QStackedWidget` is definitely the way to go. Use it as your main 'container' for your widgets and implement a default main panel widget which contains your entry items, then when you click on one you can push it to be the currently displayed widget in the stack. You could try more complicated solutions to achieve it, but it's significantly easier to do with a `QStackedWidget` and then focus on how the interaction is handled.